# Show data connected by duplicates in Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am sorry if my title makes little sense, I am learning Access as I go and I do not have all of the vocabulary. I will try to explain but I think the pictures I have will work better.
I am trying to show that two pieces of equipment are connected by the same conduit/wire (see drawn pic).[Drawing of the "connections"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZesE.jpg)
I need to be able to :

- Input the two pieces of equipment and the conduit at the same time (from combo boxes from connected already populated tables)
  ex. [equip 99 ]-[conduit 1002]-[equip100]
  [What I Have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1j0ff.png),
  [What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4YrN.png)
- Create a query that shows all of the equipment and their connected equipment.
- Create a report that shows all of the equipment, its information, and
  the connected equipment and its information.

Issues:

- Creating a to/from field does not allow all of the equipment to be displayed at the same time. ex I can only show the to but not the from on a report.

I am not afraid to use code if needed. I know I showed pics from excel but It was the best way I could think of showing what I wanted. [Here are the tables I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwjUV.png), only the circled ones are relevant.

- Assets= equipment.
- JT =Junction Table
- I know that the spaces need to be removed from the fields and table... long story.

Comment: "What I want" and "What I have" images are identical. Show sample data as text tables, not images. Show attempted SQL statement. Edit question.

Comment: If i'm understanding correctly, your many to many relationship is wrong.  You have a 3 way many to many.  so EquipmentaTbl, ConduitTbl, EquipmentbTbl all link to junction table: AConduitBs.  Then the problem reduces to inserting a record into the junction table using 3 unbound comboboxes and an insert button.  There are many examples such as: odd, can't find any even ones I've posted before

Comment: rereading I was wrong the asset table appears twice in the relationship so standard many to many relationship except give the asset table two foreign keys in the junction table.

Answer (score 0):

I will only answer the first question.  What we have here is a Self Join type of many to many relationship.
http://allenbrowne.com/ser-06.html
[image]
after hooking up the relationships jump start the form by selecting the junction table and hitting form on the ribbon.  Then add 3 unbound combo-boxes (no data source) and a button to the form header.  Prettify the form per usual until you get something like:

[image]

Per usual set the unbound combobox rowsource to the appropriate table,  then set the combobox bound colum to the key column and hide the key column by setting its width to 0.  then put the insert code in the button click event:

```
Private Sub cmdAddConnection_Click()
Dim db As Database
Set db = CurrentDb
Dim sqlString As String

sqlString = "INSERT INTO AssetConduitConnections(AssetAfk, AssetBfk, Conduitfk) VALUES(" & _
cmbAssetA & ", " & cmbAssetB & ", " & cmbConduit & ")"
'Debug.Print sqlString
db.Execute (sqlString)
Me.Requery 'show data changes on form
'Debug.Print Me.Name
db.Close
Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```

After some additional prettification like replacing the bound textboxes in the detail section with bound comboboxes I entered some data using the unbound comboboxes and the button.  the next step might be an open report button.
[image]

Comment: Thank you this is the solution!!